# Bash scope issue (?) when incrementing variable

Tags: bash, scope, increment

I have code like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

n=0
for file in *.txt
do
        tail -c1 $file | read -r _ || (
                ((n++))
                echo "$file is missing a final newline, issue #$n"
        )
done
```

But when I run it, the numbers aren't incrementing:

> a.txt is missing a final newline, issue #1
>
> b.txt is missing a final newline, issue #1

How can I fix this? It looks like a scope issue, since the 0 is incremented to 1 as though the previous increment was ignored.

Comment: Not related to your question, but the code will fail if a filename contains whitespace, using double-quotes is much safer: `tail -c1 "$file"`.

Comment: @cdarke: Good point! In my actual use case I'm using a more specific glob which doesn't permit spaces, but that should be useful for future visitors to this question. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your commands embedded between parentheses runs as a subshell, each subshell in the loop starts over with the value of n set at the parent level (n=0).

Just change the parenthesis to curly braces (a terminal semicolon or newline is required).

Comment: That's it! Such a simple thing to miss, thanks for spotting it.

Comment: Or just use a single command: `... || echo "$file is missing a final newline, issue #$((++n))"